# How to search extended attributes with filter?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to find all users who do not have a value for the extended attribute `manager`. Is this possible to do with the `-Filter` parameter or must I pipe to `Where-Object`?

I have tried all of the following:

```
$test = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Manager -notlike "*"'
$test = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Manager -ne "*"'
$test = Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter 'Manager -notlike "*"'
$test = Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter 'Manager -ne "*"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not with `-Filter`, but with `-LDAPFilter`:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(!(manager=*))'
```

assuming that you want all users who don't have a manager assigned.